# On form load, how can I automatically make listbox selections based on yes/no column in table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table (tblStates) containing two columns, "State" (string) and "Selected" (Yes/No). My form contains a multi-select listbox (lstStates) that displays all states listed in tblStates. When the form first opens, I want the listbox to already have states selected based on the "Selected" column in tblStates. Below is the code that I'm currently working on.

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim i As Integer

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblStates")

Do Until rs.EOF = True
    For i = 0 To Me.lstStates.ListCount - 1
        If rs!Selected = Yes Then
            Me.lstStates.Selected(i) = True
        End If
    Next
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

While it doesn't error out, the If condition is never met, even though most of the states have a "Yes" status in tblStates. Am I evaluating the recordset values correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't quote the "Yes" so it is considered as a variable and not a string

```vb
 If rs!Selected = "Yes" Then
```

You should add the keywords `Option Explicit` at the beginning of each of your UserForm/Module to avoid this kind of issue. You would have had a compilation error as `Yes` is not a declared variable.

**EDIT** : Let's say your `tblStates` has a field `State` and you filled the `lstStates` with some `State` values :
With `lstStates.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti` set, your code should be

```vb
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim i As Integer
Dim found as Boolean 
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT State, Selected FROM tblStates")
Do Until rs.EOF
    i = 0
    found = False
    While i < Me.lstStates.ListCount And Not found
      ' Check if the current list item matches the State from the current record
      If rs!State = Me.lstStates.List(i) Then
         ' Once this item is found, it is selected or not depending on the DB value
         Me.lstStates.Selected(i) = rs!Selected
         ' Item found for this record : not need to search other items in the list
         found = True
      End If
      i = i + 1
    Wend
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Should do the job if the lstStates has 1 column. If several columns, you have to handle the colum index here : `If rs!State = Me.lstStates.List(i, [theColumnIndex]) Then`

Comment: And as you do this, you may have another issue : you loop on your recordset and inside this loop, each time you have a record with ```Selected = "Yes"``` , you change the Selected property of the WHOLE items of lstStates.  Maybe it is what you need but it seems strange to me.

Comment: I added Option Explicit and added the double-quotes. Still no change. Thanks for the tips, though.

Comment: Check the MultiSelect property of your ListBox : did you set it well to ```fmMultiSelectMulti``` or ```fmMultiSelectExtended``` ? If it is ```fmMultiSelectSingle```, only the last item of your list is selected because only 1 item can be in your list

Comment: Right now, no records are selected on form load. The Multi Select propoerty is set to "Simple".

Comment: You can already change the MultiSelect and I guess that a ```Debug.Print(rs!Selected)``` would help to see what are the real values of your ```Selected``` field because (Yes/No) is not really a data type so you may have an Integer or a Boolean

Comment: It's boolean, but in the design view, Access labels it as "Yes/No".

Comment: I see your edit, but this doesn't resolve the problem. I want only those states with a boolean status of true/yes in tblStates to be selected in the listbox. It's starting to sound like I need to try a different method all together.

Comment: It's what I said earlier : you never try to match the items of your list with the items of your recordset. How do you want to select the right items like this ? I changed my edit, assuming your table has a ```State``` field and your list has been filled with some ```State``` values.